# can't parse xml with CDATA block using SimpleXML and Retrofit

Tags: android, xml, retrofit, cdata, simple-framework

i can't seem to get value from only element with `CDATA` block, only return empty value, hope you guys can help, this is my xml data:

```
<response>
        <error>
            <![CDATA[OK]]>
        </error>
        <limit>10</limit>
        <offset>0</offset>
        <number_of_page_results>10</number_of_page_results>
        <number_of_total_results>481312</number_of_total_results>
        <status_code>1</status_code>
        <results>
            <issue>
                <aliases/>
                <api_detail_url>
                    <![CDATA[http://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/issue/4000-6/]]>
                </api_detail_url>
                <cover_date>
                    <![CDATA[1952-10-01]]>
                </cover_date>
                <date_added>2008-06-06 11:10:16</date_added>
                <date_last_updated>2015-07-11 12:08:20</date_last_updated>
                <deck/>
                <description>
                    <![CDATA[<p>The horrors of:</p><p>- Lost race!</p><p>- The man germ!</p><p>- Man in the hood!</p><p>- The things!</p><p>-Stories behind the stars, featuring the legendary battle between Hercules, Hydra and Iolaus!</p><p>Plus, two page long prose-stories.</p>]]>
                </description>
                <has_staff_review></has_staff_review>
                <id>6</id>
                <image>
                    <icon_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static1.comicvine.com/uploads/square_avatar/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </icon_url>
                    <medium_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static2.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_medium/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </medium_url>
                    <screen_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static3.comicvine.com/uploads/screen_medium/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </screen_url>
                    <small_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static4.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_small/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </small_url>
                    <super_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static5.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_large/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </super_url>
                    <thumb_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static6.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_avatar/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </thumb_url>
                    <tiny_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://static7.comicvine.com/uploads/square_mini/5/58993/2645776-chamber_of_chills__13_cgc_8.5.jpg]]>
                    </tiny_url>
                </image>
                <issue_number>13</issue_number>
                <name>
                    <![CDATA[The Lost Race]]>
                </name>
                <site_detail_url>
                    <![CDATA[http://comicvine.gamespot.com/chamber-of-chills-magazine-13-the-lost-race/4000-6/]]>
                </site_detail_url>
                <store_date/>
                <volume>
                    <api_detail_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/volume/4050-1487/]]>
                    </api_detail_url>
                    <id>1487</id>
                    <name>
                        <![CDATA[Chamber of Chills Magazine]]>
                    </name>
                    <site_detail_url>
                        <![CDATA[http://comicvine.gamespot.com/chamber-of-chills-magazine/4050-1487/]]>
                    </site_detail_url>
                </volume>
            </issue>
        </results>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </response>
```

with my 2 model class:

```
    @Root(name = "response", strict = false)
    public class IssueWrapper extends BaseObject {
    @ElementList(name = "results")
    List<Issue> issues;
    public List<Issue> getIssues() {
        return issues;
      }
    }

    @Element(name = "issue")
    public class Issue extends BaseObject {
    @Element(name = "id")
    int id;
    @Element(name = "date_added")
    String dateAdded;
    @Element(name = "description", data = true, required = true)
    String description;
    @Element(name = "issue_number")
    int issueNumber;
    public String getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }
    public int getIssueNumber() {
        return issueNumber;
    }
}
```

Logcat output:

```
Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=true, name=description, required=true, type=void) on field 'description' public java.lang.String truongan.android.comicvineapiapp.model.Issue.description in class truongan.android.comicvineapiapp.model.Issue at line 2
```

Comment: any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```html
@Element(data = true)
```

It worked for me